# serialized a game state that had key events. retrieving a copy is without my keyboard events?

Tags: java, swing, serialization

After reading about serialization and I/O maps, I decided it  would be useful to use those to create a way of saving and loading a game map...
However, it is not working the way I'd like it to.

Here is the constructor for the map(rpggame) object,
not to be confused with the rpgmap object inside

```
public RPGGame(RPGMap newmap, RPGCursor newcursor){
        map=newmap;
        cursor=newcursor;
        //drawer=this.getGraphics();
        KeyListener listener=new KeyListener()
            {public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
                cursor.keyReleased(e);
                //if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                    //repaint();
                    //}

                }
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
                boolean determiner=cursor.keyPressed(e);
                RPGChar charref=cursor.getSelected();
                //repaint();
                if(charref!=null&&(e.getKeyCode()!=KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT&&e.getKeyCode()!=KeyEvent.VK_ENTER&&e.getKeyCode()!=KeyEvent.VK_E&&e.getKeyCode()!=KeyEvent.VK_B)){
                    RPGMapSquare squaretopaint=map.theMap[cursor.getYCoord()][cursor.getXCoord()];
                    //squaretopaint.paint(drawer, true);
                    squaretopaint.paintBlueArrow(drawer, cursor.getDirection());
                    //cursor.paint(drawer);
                }
                else{
                    repaint();
                }

            }

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
            }
        };
        addKeyListener(listener);
        setFocusable(true);
    }​
```

Now, as you see, there is a key listener in there, and it then sends the event to a cursor class.

This code is where I construct a rpggame object(from within the rpggame class's main method)

```
System.out.println("Which map do you want?");
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer=input.nextLine();

        RPGGame gamestuff;
        if(answer.compareTo("Forest")==0){
            RPGMap ForestMap=new RPGMap(8, 8, ForestMapData);//creates a new map
            RPGCursor cursor=new RPGCursor(ForestMap);//creates a new cursor object with a reference to the map
            gamestuff=new RPGGame(ForestMap, cursor);//creates new window with the map and cursor
            ForestMap.registerCanvas(gamestuff);//gives reference to window to the map
            cursor.registerCanvas(gamestuff);//gives reference to window to cursor
        }
        else {//if(answer.compareTo("Mountain")==0){
            RPGMap MountainMap=new RPGMap(8, 8, MountainMapData);
            RPGCursor cursor=new RPGCursor(MountainMap);
            gamestuff=new RPGGame(MountainMap, cursor);
            MountainMap.registerCanvas(gamestuff);
            cursor.registerCanvas(gamestuff);
        }
​
```

then I use a save method in the same main method `

```
public void saveIt(String filename) throws IOException{
        ObjectOutputStream oos=null;
        try{
            oos=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename+".dat"));
            oos.writeObject(this);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            oos.flush();
        }
    }​
```

To create a .dat file with the rpggame object constructed

from another class (dummyclass because I just want to reproduce the old map with it), I call a loading method to get the rpggame object back from the "stuff.dat" file.

```
public class dummyclass{
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        RPGGame newgame=null;
        try{
            newgame=load("stuff.dat");
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JFrame dummyframe=new JFrame("Copy");
        dummyframe.add(newgame);
        dummyframe.setVisible(true);
        dummyframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public static RPGGame load(String file) throws IOException{
        ObjectInputStream ois=null;
        RPGGame gamedata=null;
        try {
                    ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                    gamedata=(RPGGame)ois.readObject();
            } 
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, there was an error reaching the file");
            //ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            ois.close();
            return gamedata;
        }
    }​
```

After setting up the jframe and adding the retrieved rpggame object, I do get a correct visual map. However, I cannot use my keyboard input to move around the cursor(as well as some other stuff) on the dummyclass's version of the rpggame object. did it somehow lose the keylistener from the original copy in the saving and reloading?
Any help would be appreciated. This is my first dive into keyboard input and serialization to store and retrieve objects.

For your information, I did mark the cursor, map, char classes, everything, serializable, if that helps.

Comment: For goodness sake.  Use the `{}` button for code formatting (those are not 'runnable snippets') and some upper case letters where appropriate!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Object seralisation is not a good choice for the long term storage of objects, instead, consider using something like [JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/). `KeyListener` is a poor choice for keyboard input as it suffers from a focus related issue, consider using the key bindings API instead, see [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

I think in this scenario you probably would be better off recreating the KeyListener after the deserialization has completed.  Also, I can't tell what properties are serialized and which are not but why not try changing your constructor to something like this:

```
public RPGGame(RPGMap newmap, RPGCursor newcursor){
    map=newmap;
     setCursor(newcursor);
}​
private void setCursor(RPGCursor newcursor){
    cursor=newcursor;
    //drawer=this.getGraphics();
    KeyListener listener=new KeyListener()
        {public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
            cursor.keyReleased(e);
            //if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                //repaint();
                //}

            }
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            boolean determiner=cursor.keyPressed(e);
            RPGChar charref=cursor.getSelected();
            //repaint();
            if(charref!=null&&(e.getKeyCode()!=KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT&&e.getKeyCode()!=KeyEvent.VK_ENTER&&e.getKeyCode()!=KeyEvent.VK_E&&e.getKeyCode()!=KeyEvent.VK_B)){
                RPGMapSquare squaretopaint=map.theMap[cursor.getYCoord()][cursor.getXCoord()];
                //squaretopaint.paint(drawer, true);
                squaretopaint.paintBlueArrow(drawer, cursor.getDirection());
                //cursor.paint(drawer);
            }
            else{
                repaint();
            }

        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
        }
    };
    addKeyListener(listener);
    setFocusable(true);

}
```

Now that you have seperated out the KeyListener registration you should call it after deserialization, I don't think it is wise to serialize the key listeners, you would be better served by re-registering.  Remember serialization is about storing object graphs, it isn't useful for storing references to input devices or things like that:

```
public static RPGGame load(String file) throws IOException{
    ObjectInputStream ois=null;
    RPGGame gamedata=null;
    try {
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                gamedata=(RPGGame)ois.readObject();
                gamedata.setCursor(gamedata.cursor);
        } 
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, there was an error reaching the file");
        //ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        ois.close();
        return gamedata;
    }
}​
```

Comment: alright, so I tried those changes, but now it is failing to actually load, giving an exception with trying to load the file.... more specifically, an invalid class exception(and it is not mentioning any of the object references within the rpggame object, which is odd)

Comment: wait no, it is working mostly now(maybe I messed up with compilation). I have to fix the blue arrow thing, but that may have to do with the graphics object drawer being static(I read somewhere static doesn't play well with serializing/deserializing).thank you for helping with that... java can be so hard

Comment: can't, that was my first post ever, not enough reputation

Comment: nice... now I can continue doing other work for this game... I have really been investing a lot of my time to making it, and that will be helpful for actually having save files, so that is nice